# Dynamic XML files using ashx

Tags: .net, xml, ashx, directory

I'm having an issue where I try to pull the filePath of an XML file using the XML web control. The XML file is stored in a different directory and I am using an ashx file to serve it up. The ashx file works by appending the XML file name to the end of the string.

```
Dim oXML As New System.Web.UI.WebControls.Xml
oXML.DocumentSource = Server.MapPath("xmlHandler.ashx") & "?xml=sampleXMLfile.xml"
oXML.TransformSource = Server.MapPath("xmlStyles.xslt")
oXML.DataBind()
```

This doesn't seem to be working for me, and I was wondering if pulling the XML into the code behind is the only way?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's hard to tell what's wrong without seeing any code whatsoever. Personally I probably *would* use a code-behind, but could you at least show us what you're trying?

Comment: There you go sir. Thanks for the swift reply.

Comment: You've shown code which tries to use a mixture of a filename and a URL query. I'd be very surprised to see that working. You still haven't shown us the ashx itself though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MapPath` maps a HTTP path/virtual path to a physical folder: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx

So the result, `c:\file\on\disk\etc\xmlHandler.ashx?xml=sampleXMLfile.xml`, doesn't make sense: it's not a local filename.

If you want to download that URL, take a look at the `WebClient` class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.80).aspx

...then set `DocumentSource` to an `XmlDocument` loaded from the resulting downloaded data, or a string, or a local file path, as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.xml.documentsource(v=vs.80).aspx  (As you can see, you can't set `DocumentSource` to a URL - not that you're providing a valid URL anyway!)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was trying to build the user viewing side of the XML while a fellow developer built a file system for pushing and pulling the XML files out of a separate directory. He had setup an ashx file to preview the XML; however this complicated my work and led me to ask my question here.

To solve the problem I just bypassed the ashx file and used the code it held to pull the xml to string and bind it to the Xml webcontrol.

```
Dim fRead = New IO.FileStream(filePath, IO.FileMode.Open)
Dim sReader = New IO.StreamReader(fRead)
xmlString = sReader.ReadToEnd()
fRead.Close()
sReader.Close()

Dim oXML As New System.Web.UI.WebControls.Xml
oXML.DocumentContent = xmlString 
oXML.TransformSource = Server.MapPath("getTSP.xslt")
oXML.DataBind()
Panel1.Controls.Add(oXML)
```

Thanks again for your help.